# loop for jquery click

Tags: jquery, slide

I am wondering if someone could help me with a jquery loop or script. When a button is clicked i woud like to animate a div to slide across the screen, when clicked again another div slides down. When the button is clicked AGAIN another div and so on, so on.

Here is the html mark up ive done so far

```
<div class="page-container">

<h2 class="gallery-heading"> WAIKANAE BEACH HOUSE </h2>
    <img src="images/waikanae/next button.png" id="gallery-next"/>


    <div id="slider">

      <section class="horizontal-gallery">
        <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-horizontal"/>
        <p class="horizontal-gallery-text">Test text.</p>
      </section>

      <section class="vertical-gallery">
        <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-horizontal"/>
        <p class="horizontal-gallery-text">Test text.</p>
      </section>

      <section class="horizontal-gallery">
        <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-horizontal"/>
        <p class="horizontal-gallery-text">Test text.</p>
      </section>

    </div> 

$('#gallery-next').click(function() {
   $('.horizontal-gallery').hide('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
});
```

Comment: I have added in the question but have no idea. Should i use a loop?

Comment: Same animation on the divs with the same class. eg vertical-gallery to slide vertically

Comment: @Digby I notice you haven't yet accepted or upvoted answers. Please note that this is an important part of acknowledging assistance. Those who have worked to help you are relying on you to do your part, also. (Accepted answer = 15 rep; upvote = 10 rep; both together = 25.) Thanks D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described, you'll need:

```
$('div selector').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
```

And also:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   //sliding code
});
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide
And: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I suspect your post was downvoted b/c someone didn't understand that the hide('slide') method is from jQueryUI and requires that library. Your solution contains the answer, so I reversed the downvote. (Yes, I saw that you referenced jQueryUI in your sources but at least one person missed it).

Comment: Thanks for the backup! I suppose I could've taken the effort to write a more comprehensive example, but since the question was vague, I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be *exactly* what you want, but hopefully you will find some useful code ideas. Take what works, and post another question to fine-tune your solution. It looks a bit messy because I included the javascript and stylesheet within the page rather than making them separate documents.

Note that the hide('slide') method is from jQueryUI and you must include that library also.

Note also that IDs were added to each section element, as per the suggestion of another poster who unfortunately deleted their post.

This is a fully working example (just ensure your images exist. They can be different images)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var totalslides = 3;
        var slidenum = 0;
        var slidenext = 0;
        var slideType = '';
        $(function(){
            $('#gallery-next').data('counter',1);
            $('#gallery-next').click(function() {
               slidenum = parseInt($('#gallery-next').data('counter'));
               slidenext = slidenum+1
               slideType = $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').attr('class')
               slideType = slideType.split('-')[0]
               if (slideType=='horizontal') slideType='up';
               else slideType = 'left';
//alert('Next slideType is: ' + slideType)
                //hide(slide) is a jQueryUI function, so ensure you include that lib
               $('#'+slidenum+'-slide').hide('slide',{direction:slideType},500);
               $('#'+slidenext+'-slide').fadeIn(1000);
               slidenum = slidenum % totalslides + 1;
               $('#gallery-next').data('counter',slidenum);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" >
        .init-hidden {display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-container">

    <h2 class="gallery-heading"> WAIKANAE BEACH HOUSE </h2>
    <img src="images/waikanae/next button.png" id="gallery-next"/>

    <div id="slider">
        <section id="1-slide" class="horizontal-gallery">
            <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-horizontal"/>
            <p class="horizontal-gallery-text">Test text.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="2-slide" class="vertical-gallery init-hidden">
            <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-vertical"/>
            <p class="vertical-gallery-text">Test text.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="3-slide" class="horizontal-gallery init-hidden">
            <img src="images/waikanae/crafar_h1.jpg" class="waikanae-gallery-horizontal"/>
            <p class="horizontal-gallery-text">Test-text.</p>
        </section>
    </div> <!-- endDiv slider -->
</div> <!-- endDiv page-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, works nearly exactly to what I am after a few css changes. THANK YOU

Comment: One last little question, when the image is sliding up you can only see a small amount of the slide, it then fades in from where the existing image was. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Not off-hand, no. You should create another question regarding that aspect of this problem. Don't hesitate to post multiple questions related to different aspects of the same problem. By the way, it is a good idea to always accept an answer to your posts, and to upvote any other helpful posts, including comments. This will help you to gain rep points on SO and will encourage others to help you more.